# What are the use cases of Blaze.render

Tags: meteor-blaze, meteor

Can somebody please help me understand when and why or under what conditions `Blaze.render()/Blaze.renderWithData` should be used?

Thanks.

Comment: To insert templates dynamically. For example, I use it in [my package](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) ([the code](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal/blob/master/main.js#L20)) to dynamically insert bootstrap 3 modals. In most cases, using [Template.dynamic](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

All of the methods on `Blaze` are an API that you could use if you were implementing your own templating system with Meteor. If you are making a Meteor app using regular Spacebars templates defined in HTML files, you will very rarely need any of these methods.

One case you could use Blaze.render() is to interact with some other HTML or templating library. For example, you could use JQuery to create an element, then use `Blaze.render()` to insert a template into that element.